# Magento Slider issue

Tags: php, magento, slider, banner

I have a magento site and I want to add a slider to the home page. I tried a free plugin and it installed correctly but when I put it on the cms page it just showed a blank div (the div I had around the code). Thinking that it was a bug in the plugin I bought another more advanced plugin and the same thing is happening. I tried testing the standard magento slider widget and It will show the banners but as a static image not rotating.

Any idea what this could be? Anyone else have this issue and fixed it?

Comment: What is the magento version ? How are you adding it to the home page ? Paste your `local.xml` if you are using it please.

Comment: Magento ver. 1.14.0.1 (Enterprise) and I am adding it through the CMS for the plugin here is the code used {{block type="slideshow/slideshow" template="slideshow/slideshow.phtml"}} for the magento rotator just the magento widget

Comment: Thanks Nilcot, The files were installed into the wrong folders! Should of checked that first instead of assuming they were installed correctly

Comment: Did it solve the problem ? Great =)

Answer (score 0):

These are some things you may check:

- The module structure (under `app/code/local` ?);
- If the module is active (`app/etc/modules/`);
- The correct directory structure of the module (which determines the `type="XXX/XXX"` parameter);
- If there is a `slideshow.phtml` in the `app/design` structure and the design `theme` it's located.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
      jQuery('#recently').bxSlider({
        auto: false,
        pager: false,
        slideWidth: 80,
        slideMargin:15,
        controls: true,
        infiniteLoop:false,
        minSlides: 1,
        maxSlides: 4,
        moveSlides: 1,
        preloadImages:'all'
      });
    });     
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.smartparcelbox.com/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/jquery.bxslider.js"></script>
```